# How to populate user X session environment on CentOS7

Tags: centos, x11, gnome, gnome3, desktop-environment

I'm working on a machine where I do not have admin rights. So I self compiled some applications into environment modules (shared with other people, we're on a NFS) that can be loaded using `module load <application>`, using [`Lmod`](https://lmod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), that loads the correct environment variables (e.g. `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, etc...) into the shell.

What I would like to achieve now is to let `gdm` know where to look for `.desktop` files and all related stuff tho show the applications in the application menu of GNOME. In particular `Lmod` can restore a default set of modules doing `module restore <name_of_the_set>` and so I need a place where I can put that command in order to make `gdm` aware of new (or renewed) env variables as `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`.

On CentOS7, `$HOME/.xsession` does not seem to be read by GNOME session. Where should I look into?